# gnome: How to set lv3:rwin_switch xkb option in tweak tools

Tags: gnome, keyboard, keyboard-layout, gnome-tweak-tool

I set my keyboard layout like this:

```
setxkbmap -layout us -variant altgr-intl -option '' -option caps:escape -option altwin:swap_alt_win lv3:rwin_switch
```

which is fine, as long as I do not plugin and plug out an external keyboard,  or hit the "switch keyboard layout" key. In these cases I have to go to the terminal and redo this command.

I would like this options to be more permanent, so I try to set them in the "tweak tool".
But I cannot find an option, that correspond to "lv3:rwin_switch" which sets my lv3 key (for international characters) to my right win key.

I tried around, but the options are a little confusing. Can this be done in the tweak-tool?

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps adding a **udev** rule to run the same command when keyboard commands may solve the problem.

1. First connect your external keyboard, and do `lsusb` to find the hardware ID. It would look something like

   `Bus 002 Device 002: ID 04f2:0402 Chicony Electronics Co., Ltd Genius LuxeMate i200 Keyboar`. The id is **04f2:0402**.
2. Then we add a UDEV rule. To edit the file, do `sudo nano /etc/udev/rules.d/00-usb-keyboards.rules`, fill the text file with something like

   ```
   ACTION=="add", ATTRS{idVendor}=="YOUR_VENDOR(04f2 for me)", ATTRS{idProduct}=="YOUR_PRODUCT(0402 for me)", RUN+="/usr/local/bin/kbd_udev", OWNER="USERNAME"
   ```

   Note that you should change the **USERNAME** field.
   And with this we tell udev to run the script whenever the device with matching vendor and product ID is connected.
3. Now we get to the script file `/usr/local/bin/kbd_udev`, do `sudo nano /usr/local/bin/kbd_udev` and fill it in with the script below

   ```
   #!/bin/bash
   export DISPLAY=:0
   su YOURUSERNAME -c "setxkbmap -layout us -variant altgr-intl -option '' -option caps:escape -option altwin:swap_alt_win lv3:rwin_switch" &> /tmp/kbd_temp
   ```

   Again, make sure to change **YOURUSERNAME** with your username.
4. After writing the script, you need to make it executable. To do so..

   ```
   sudo chmod 755 /usr/local/bin/kbd_udev
   ```
5. Finally, tell udev to reload it's rules, run `udevadm control --reload-rules`
6. Optional, but you can test to see if the command worked, by looking in the `/tmp/` directory. Do `cat /tmp/kbd_temp`, if there are any errors, you should be able to see them.

Comment: Your answer seems to stop abruptly. My keyboard is this: Bus 001 Device 010: ID 1241:1503 Belkin Keyboard

Comment: Yeah sorry, it got submitted before I finished editing it. Could you try the next steps and tell what you get ?